# Visual Studio 2015 .Net project Build error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

After a code merge, I am getting the following issue when trying to build.

```
The project currently contains references to more than one version of 'System.Web.Mvc', a direct reference to version 2.0.0.0 and an indirect reference to version 5.2.3.0. 
Change the direct reference to use version 5.2.3.0 (or higher) of System.Web.Mvc.
```

I cannot see any references to System.Web.Mvc under references for this project.
There is one ref in the Web.config

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Removing this makes no difference, I get the same error.

After removing the ref from packages.config and going into NuGet to reinstall the package, it gets most of the way through, then fails with

```
Failed to update binding redirects for {project path} : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

Does anyone have any ideas abtou what to try next? It's a pretty big project, I would rather not have to reconstruct the whole thing...

Comment: Have you try to remove all of the files in the bin folder and then rebuilding the project? The error reported scenario maybe occurred If application created under one .Net Framework and application’s Target Framework is different from referenced framework, so please check whether application’s reference DLLs are referred same DLL version as Target Framework version.

Comment: I found the reference under "Extensions" (and it was not needed, so I removed it), and can now build (after removing and re-referecncing some otherr dlls that could n ot be found). I have all sorts of other weird errors,, like when adding an MVC page, and things not being able to be updated (or found) in web.config so I am going for a repair of VS.

Comment: Good idea on the target frameworks, though. I have had that be the issue before, especially within a solution.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue. You can convert your comment to the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and easier to find the answer. If you have other issues you can post a new post for free, I will keep follow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reference under "Extensions" (and it was not needed, so I removed it), and can now build (after removing and re-referecncing some other dlls that could not be found).